# Bike component opinions

Tags: mountain-bike

I am looking at buying my first mountain bike, a big moment I know!

Is there a small/big difference between the Shimano MT400 and the MT200 brakes? Is it worth thinking about an upgraded brake spec for a first MTB purchase?

I am looking at 2 wheel sizes, one being 27.5"x2.8" and 29"x2.25"
I heard wider tires give a smoother ride over rocky/rooted trails. What are some considerations that might lead me to choose 29" vs 27.5"?

Do tubeless-ready tires come with a tube pre-installed? or does this depend on a retailers own choice?

Can anyone provide any input or preference for the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must test them. Especially because it is the first mtb you will buy. If you really cannot test them, buy the one that has the best possibility of return. If none can be returned, buy the cheapest and use the money to adapt the fitting.
The biggest difference reg. tyres is not they are wider, but that they are 27.5" vs 29". They may be completely different bikes, simply due to that, but you cannot know for sure you will need wider tires. If wider = better, every mtb would look like a fatbike.
Disclaimer: I don't know the bikes you posted, neither I clicked on the links.

Comment: What are you going to use the bike for? I don’t know much about MTBs but the Roscoe seems to be more focused on the downhill side of things while the Boardman looks more cross country (1.2kg lighter, no dropper seatpost, narrower tires). I guess the Roscoe is a great alternative to a full suspension bike.

Comment: If you edit the question to ask what factors you should consider when trying to select an entry level MTB, and you give the examples of wheel size, dropper post, and minor differences in the brake spec, I would likely vote to reopen the question. In general, we don’t focus on product recommendations here, per our site FAQ.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I have updated my question above

Comment: @EarlGrey I will call around my local bike shops to see what is in stock so I can get a feel for the different features. Hopefully they are in stock as bikes have seem to become a rare commodity recently

Comment: @Michael I will be using it for rocky/rooted trails at the start as they are the closest to me. It will mostly be trail based with little road use. I think my budget for a MTB is max 1300 for my first bike and full suspensions seem to be very pricey and I don't think I would benefit from them as a beginner.

Comment: Another reason for closing this question is that it (now) asks about brakes, wheel sizes, and tubeless tyre tubes.  That's three relatively unrelated questions, and would need to be separately asked to get on-point answers.  Posters do better when they don't have to address multiple separate points.